# Publisher Action on VisualForce Page

Tags: publisher

Can we have a publisher action on a visualforce page?
The scenario which I am looking at is:

1. Having a plus {+} icon at the bottom-right of the VF page
2. On click of the plus {+} icon, the user should be shown the available actions to the VF Page.

I am aware about displaying a button which would act like a action.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to embed Chatter on the Visualforce Page and add your Publish Action to the appropriate Page Layout.

[Doc for chatter:feed](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_chatter_feed.htm).

Example:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">
    <chatter:feed entityId="{!Account.Id}" showPublisher="true"/>
</apex:page>
```